# Why does int("0xff",16) compute but, say, int("hello", 16) not?

Tags: python-3.x, string, integer, int

Forgive me if this is a stupid question. I am currently in the beginning stages of learning Python via a Skillsoft course. One of the examples the instructor used was: `int("0xff",16)` and it computed, and printed 255.

I am just confused because, while I understand that 0xff is "the hexcidecimal number FF which has an integer value of 255" (thanks, Google), I don't understand how "0xff" isn't considered a string due to the quotations. When I tried `int("hello",16)` I was met with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    int("hello", 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: 'hello'
```

How can `int("0xff",16)` compute but not `int("hello",16)` when both "0xff" and "hello" are strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `"0xff"` is a string that represents a hexadecimal number (base `16`), and hexadecimal numbers' digits range from `0` to `9` and from `a` to `f`, `"hello"` has `"h"`, `"l"`, and `"o"`, none of which are valid hexadecimal digits.

The `"0x"` in `"0xff"` is just there to specify that this is a hexadecimal string, the actual number is just `"ff"` (`int("ff", 16) ==> 255`).

To see why strings are allowed, consider a number in the `17`-base number system (`0-9` and `a-g`), how would you use `int` with a number such as `"gg"` in this system, `int("gg", 17)`.

You can use `int` with `"hello"`, but only using a base greater than or equal to `25` (because `10 + ord(max("hello")) - 97 + 1 == 25`), `int("hello", 25) ==> 6873049`.